# Is it possible to use SIPML5 without RTP/SAVP

Tags: html, webrtc

I was wondering if anyone of you got knowledge about the open source html5 sip client, its called SIPML5.

I can't seem to figure out how to get working without the use of RTP/SAVPF.

So my question is is it possible to use RTP/SAVP instead of RTP/SAVPF?

Answer (score 0):

Lie.  Before passing your SDP in, just replace all instances of RTP/SAVP with RTP/SAVPF.  It should work just fine.

RTP/SAVPF and RTP/SAVP are fairly compatible.  The 'F' indicates an RTP profile where the timing of RTCP feedback is more relaxed.  Since most RTP endpoints don't check RTCP feedback timing strictly, an RTP/SAVP endpoint will usually interoperate with an RTP/SAVPF endpoint.